# Change ActiveMQ Log4j version

Tags: gradle, log4j, activemq-classic

I have a Gradle project that uses `activemq-all` as a dependency, and within the project I use Log4j that comes with ActiveMQ jar. The latest ActiveMQ version is still using Log4j 1.2.x, and I want to use the latest version of Log4j.

I included Log4j as a separate dependency, but Gradle won't detect it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If the program is a client-side only, you should depend on activemq-client instead of activemq-all.

activemq-client depends on slf4j-api, and you can use the slf4j bridge to log4j or log4j2.